# Making a simple MySQL backup script to be run via cron, having permissions issues

Tags: backup, cron, bash, mysql

This is a very basic mysqldump script that will do a dump and store it locally.

Running mysqldump by itself works fine as does gzip (i.e. they are where they need to be in my path)

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --database $DBNAME --opt --single-transaction -u $USER -p $PASS
```

But when I try to pipe the output to gzip and then write that to a file I run into an error:

```
/var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/mysqlbackup.sh: line 18: /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/mehbackup.sql.gz: No such file or directory
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Here is the line 18 referenced in the error:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --database $DBNAME --opt --single-transaction -u$USER -p$PASS | /usr/bin/gzip -9 > $OUTDIR$OUTFILE
```

That error number 32 seems to be a broken pipe error so... I'm assuming that , since mysqldump can run fine, I am having an issue writing the results? A permissions issue maybe?

The permissions on the dir I am writing to are 766 (rwxrw-rw-)

I am running this under super user permissions (`su`)

I want to set this up to run via cron but until I figure out why this is failing... no love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can do this:

```
$ echo "woo" | gzip > asdf.gz
$ gunzip asdf.gz
cat asdf
```

That should tell you that your gzip stuff is working fine. If you're not doing your gzip stuff the way I just did it, maybe try it the way I just did it.

In other words, try this:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --database $DBNAME --opt --single-transaction -u $USER -p $PASS | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/dump.gz
```

Comment: What I find missing is that you don't have a `>` in the `mysqldump` command where as you did in your example regarding `woo`. Therefore, this command worked for me: `/usr/bin/mysqldump --database $DBNAME --opt --single-transaction -u $USER -p $PASS | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/dump.gz` NOTE: the `>` after `gzip`

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: could you please edit it?

Comment: Done.............................

Answer (score 1):

Check path:

```
file /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/
ls -ald /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/
```

and create dir:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another distinct possibility: you have "/var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackup" in one instance and "/var/www/vhosts/meh/mysqlbackups" in another instance. Maybe that's it.

Comment: Ugh, sorry. That was a typo on my part while putting this in. It is correct in the actual script. Good point though, as such things can so easily be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me I wasn't executing the cron as root user, so I had to change folder owner and permission

```
chown user1 /home/user1/public_html/backups
chmod 755 /home/user1/public_html/backups
```

Then I was getting the same error: No such file or directory mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

I add a dot before the public_html (the root folder for user1) and worked fine.

```
mysqldump -u user1_usr -h localhost -p'123123' db_db1 | gzip -f > ./public_html/backups/db-2015-11-14-0722.sql.gz
```

Comment: the `pwd` for personal cron jobs (`crontab -e`) is your `$HOME` directory